# Why is my node.js registration function not working as expected with express and prisma?

Tags: node.js, authentication, prisma

So, I have built the register function and when I test using insomnia I get a
[POST] => url:: /auth/register on the terminal of my VSCODE and no error returnt neither on the json body of insomnia nor the terminal. What happens is the preview box in insomnia where I should get the returnt json body just keeps loading indefinetly. I will leave all the code and the prisma schema below, for reference::

```
import { PrismaClient, User, UserRole } from "@prisma/client";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { sign } from "jsonwebtoken";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export async function register(
  email: string,
  password: string,
  role: UserRole = UserRole.USER,
  firstName: string,
  lastName?: string
) {
  /* console.log(
    "Register function called with:",
    email,
    password,
    role,
    firstName,
    lastName
  ); */
  const user = await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      email,
      role,
      password: await bcrypt.hash(password, 8),
      profile: {
        create: {
          firstName,
          lastName,
        },
      },
    },
  });


  console.log("User created", user);

  return createToken(user);
}

export const findById = async (id: string) =>
  prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: { id },
    include: { profile: true },
  });

export async function attemptLogin(email: string, password: string) {
  const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
    where: {
      email,
      deleted: false,
    },
  });

  const match = user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password));

  if (!user || !match) {
    throw new Error("Bad credentials");
  }

  return createToken(user);
}

function createToken(user: User): string {
  const token = sign(
    {
      exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 60 * 24 * 180,
      email: user.email,
      user_id: user.id,
      role: user.role,
    },
    process.env.JWT_SECRET!
  );

  return token;
}
```

// controller:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { register } from "../../services/auth";

export default async (request: Request, response: Response) => {
  try {
    const { login, password, firstName, lastName } = request.body;

    /* console.log("Request body:", request.body); */

    const token = await register(login, password, firstName, lastName);

    /* console.log("Token:", token); */

    return response.json({ token });
  } catch (e: any) {
    return response.status(400).json({
      code: 400,
      error: "Bad Request",
      message: e.message,
    });
  }
};
```

```
model User {
  id          String    @id @default(cuid()) @unique
  email       String    @unique
  password    String
  profile Profile? 
  role        UserRole  @default(USER)
  createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime  @updatedAt
  orders      Order[]
  reservations Reservation?
  deleted Boolean @default(false)
}

model Profile {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  firstName String   @db.VarChar(255)
  lastName  String?  @db.VarChar(255)
  userId    String   @unique
  user      User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}.
```

And the middleware:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { verify } from "jsonwebtoken";
import { ExtendedPayload } from "../models/token";
import { findById } from "../services/auth";

const publicEndpoints = ["/auth/login", "/auth/register"];

export function verifyToken(
  request: Request,
  response: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) {
  if (publicEndpoints.includes(request.path)) {
    return next();
  }

  const authHeader = request.headers.authorization;

  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1];

  if (!token) {
    return response.sendStatus(401).json({
      code: 401,
      message: "Token not found",
    });
  }

  verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET!, async (error, payload) => {
    if (error) {
      return response.status(403).json({
        code: 403,
        message: error.message,
      });
    }

    const { user_id: id } = payload as ExtendedPayload;

    const user = await findById(id);

    if (!user) {
      return response.status(404).json({
        code: 404,
        message: "User not found",
      });
    }

    request.user = user;

    next();
  });
}
```

As you can see I have tried different console.logs but I got nothing back on the terminal. I know this is a very lengthy question so very big thanks in advance if anyone chooses to take they're time to help me out.

I have used a very similar function in a previous project and everything worked fine. Main differences would be the parameters on the register function and that I used uuid for that project and am using cuid for this project(wouldn't think that's the issue)...